# What are the references of the form [D blah] in Giraud's cohomologie nonabelienne?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

In Giraud's book "Cohomologie non-abelienne", the author repeatedly cites sources using something like [D blah]. E.g., Chapter 1, section 1, first line: "Nous renvoyons à [D 1] et à [SGA 1 VI]..."

The problem is there's nothing in the bibliography labelled [D]. The closest thing are two papers of Dedecker's. The first paper does not seem to be the right one, and the second one (published in "Lille"), my university doesn't seem to have access to.

What reference is he citing?

Comment: "11. Giraud,J.: Méthode de la descente. Mémoires Soc. Math. Fr. 2 (1964) (cité [D])." I suspect this.

Comment: I agree with Wojowu. Compare "16. Grothendieck, A., Dieudonné, J.: Eléments de Géométrie Algébrique. P. U. F. (cité [EGA])." @Wojowu it would be good to make this an answer, even CW if you don't want rep from it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the bibliography you can find the following item:

> 11. Giraud,J.: Méthode de la descente. Mémoires Soc. Math. Fr. 2 (1964) (cité [D]).

My understanding then is that citationd like [D 1] refer to specific sections or results in the reference [D], which is above. Note something similar is done with references to EGA or specific volumes of SGA - abbreviated name followed by a section/result number for a citation.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @stupid_question_bot for what it's worth, here's Giraud's paper: http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=MSMF_1964__2__R3_0